# Cannot connect DataGrip to database hosted using XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, datagrip

I am currently trying to learn MySQL.

I have used XAMPP to setup my database on PhpMyAdmin.
**suppose,**

```
  host: localhost <br>
   port: 3306 <br>
   database name: db1<br>
   username: user1<br>
   password: pass1<br>
   URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
```

When I put in the above information into DataGrip (File -> Data Sources -> Add MySQL) and Test the connection, it fails. Am I missing something notation wise?

Comment: "...it fails" is pretty vague.  Any error messages?

Comment: "no packets received from server"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  XAMPP installed, this is easy to do.

1) Open your browser and enter http://localhost/phpmyadmin. This will bring you to the MySQL setup page:

2) Enter a name for the database, then click on the Create button

3) Ensure the database was successfully created:

This database can now be used by any application that requires a MySQL

Also make sure you are able to connect to Mysql database from your local machine.Test the connectivity by pining the port or manually open any database connection using mysql client

Comment: I know how to create a database (it has been created). My problem is I don't want to work in PhpMyAdmin, I want to work in DataGrip (jet brains IDE) and I would like to import the data to jet brains.

Comment: Can you please write to maxim.sobolevskiy@jetbrains.com and send a screenshot of connection window?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAMPP check the Port used for MySQL and enter it in the port section of data source inside Datagrip (In my case by Default port 3306 was used for MySQL).
Enter your DB username and pass and hit test connection!